# iOS: Pattern for mapping view inputs to NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsnotificationcenter

I am building an app with a view controller that represents a form for creating and editing a `Task` object. It has the following behaviour:

1. On initialization of the controller, a `Task` object (`NSManagedObject` subclass) is initialized in the MOC
2. `NSNotificationCenter` observers are set up for each input in the view.
3. When an input's value is changed, the corresponding property of the `Task` object is updated via the observers' assigned method. (eg. `- (void)taskNameChanged;`)
4. When the user taps `Save`, the `Task` object is committed to the data store. If the user taps `cancel`, the `Task` object is discarded from the MOC.

I have a feeling that there is a better way to do this. What is the most common pattern for this type of transaction?

Comment: How have you configured observations? Usually you would use target-action on the input controls... Other than that it sounds fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's uncommon to use notifications in cases like this. The question you need to ask is: Do you need to update it all the time? Most of the times you won't. I usually just the values when the Save button is tapped.

In case you would have to check the values earlier, you still don't want to use notifications. I usually go for hooking up a `IBAction` to one of the events in Interface Builder. Another option is using the `delegate`, in that case your `UIViewController` instance would implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.

Comment: I ended up abandoning the close mapping between the inputs and the Task object and instead I'm now creating a new Task object on save. My particular use case doesn't really require much more complexity than this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, iOS lacks Cocoa Bindings, so you end up having to implement a light version yourself.

I did this for our app, and it ended up working well. I used KVO instead of notifications, for two-way binding. I created a dictionary mapping between the object properties and UI elements, and using KVC set up the binding when the view is loaded. In my implementation, I added an option to hint which value should take precedence (this is less valuable for data<->UI, but I wanted something more generic). Eventually, I added support for block-based data transformation between binded objects, so that UI could present text, while the data backing object could hold different types of data.

Please note that UIKit is not KVO compliant. I created KVO-compliant versions of `UITextField` and `UITextView`, by listening to notifications and sending the appropriate KVO messages.

While, I cannot post code of this, I hope this gives you ideas regarding your further adventures.

Comment: Please note that nothing in `UIKit` is guaranteed to be KVO-compliant. It might work for now, but it can break in the future. So I wouldn't recommend using it, unless there isn't a good alternative.

Comment: @GuidoHendriks You are correct, it actually doesn't work. I created KVO-compliant versions of `UITextField` and `UITextView` for my needs. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Other than that, I think that in most cases it would not be necessary to instantly know when the change happens. Because you'll tap the "Save" button when it needs to be saved, that's when you do need the actual values.

Comment: @GuidoHendriks Depends on the use case. In some cases, you may want to persist temporary values, for example if the user kills the app, or worse things happen.